# Column Transformer with OneHotEncoder issue when passing df

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pipeline

I am currently trying to learn how to use Pipelines and Column Transformers, but am encountering difficulty when applying them to a dataframe. I am working on a Kaggle housing dataset which is based on Iowa homes or something along those lines (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data). I have already filled Null values with dataframe column means and 'None' for columns which have strings. I am now trying to create a columns transformer to apply the OneHotEncoder to columns that only have string objects in them using:

```
obj_list=[x for x in df.columns if (df[x].dtype!= np.int) & (df[x].dtype!=np.float)] #Columns with non-numerical values

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

ct=make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),obj_list),remainder='passthrough') #Create a Column Transformer
pipe=make_pipeline(ct)

outcome=pipe.fit_transform(df.values)
```

But I receive a value error:

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

If I use a dataframe instead:

```
outcome=pipe.fit_transform(df)
#I can now do
df_1=pd.DataFrame(outcome,columns=ct.get_feature_names())
```

I get

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1460,1), indices imply (1460,288)
```

because the one hot transformer seems to have bunched all the values up into one column.
The column transformer features are retained but look funky:

```
list(ct.get_feature_names())
#['onehotencoder__x0_C (all)', 'onehotencoder__x0...']
```

Can someone take a look and possibly also explain why the output names are so weird?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the one hot encoder actually created an np sparse matrix!